# get the size of a variable batch dimension

Tags: tensorflow

assuming the input to the network is a `placeholder` with variable batch size, i.e.:

```
x = tf.placeholder(..., shape=[None, ...])
```

is it possible to get the shape of `x` after it has been fed?  `tf.shape(x)[0]` still returns `None`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If `x` has a variable batch size, the only way to get the actual shape is to use the [`tf.shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#shape) operator. This operator returns a symbolic value in a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor), so it can be used as the input to other TensorFlow operations, but to get a concrete Python value for the shape, you need to pass it to [`Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run).

```
x = tf.placeholder(..., shape=[None, ...])
batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]  # Returns a scalar `tf.Tensor`

print x.get_shape()[0]  # ==> "?"

# You can use `batch_size` as an argument to other operators.
some_other_tensor = ...
some_other_tensor_reshaped = tf.reshape(some_other_tensor, [batch_size, 32, 32])

# To get the value, however, you need to call `Session.run()`.
sess = tf.Session()
x_val = np.random.rand(37, 100, 100)
batch_size_val = sess.run(batch_size, {x: x_val})
print x_val  # ==> "37"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the shape of the tensor x using `x.get_shape().as_list()`. For getting the first dimension (batch size) you can use `x.get_shape().as_list()[0]`.