# Range of size of tensor's dimension - tf.range

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to define an operation for a NN I'm implementing, but to do so I need to iterate over the dimension of a tensor. I have a small working example below.

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
idx = [[i] for i in tf.range(X.get_shape()[0])]
```

This produces an error stating

```
ValueError: Cannot convert an unknown Dimension to a Tensor: ?
```

When using the same code but using `tf.shape` instead, resulting in the code being

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
idx = [[i] for i in tf.range(tf.shape(X)[0])]
```

Gives the following error

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.
```

The way that I'm implementing this NN, the `batch_size` isn't defined until the training function, which is at the end of the code. This is just where I'm building the graph itself, so the `batch_size` isn't known by this point, and it can't be fixed as the training `batch_size` and the test set batch_sizes are different.

What is the best way to fix this? This is the last thing keeping my code from running, as I got it to run with a fixed `batch_size`, though those results aren't useful. I've been pouring over the TensorFlow API Documentation and stack overflow for weeks to no avail.

I've also tried to feed in a placeholder into the range, so when I'm running the test/training set the code would be the following

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
bs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

def My_Function(X):
    # Do some stuff to X
    idx = [[i] for i in tf.range(bs)]
    # return some tensor

A = tf.nn.relu(My_Function(X))
```

However, this gives the same error as above

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the tf.shape(x) instead.

```
x = tf.placeholder(..., shape=[None, ...])
batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]  # Returns a scalar `tf.Tensor`

print x.get_shape()[0]  # ==> "?"

# You can use `batch_size` as an argument to other operators.
some_other_tensor = ...
some_other_tensor_reshaped = tf.reshape(some_other_tensor, [batch_size, 32, 32])

# To get the value, however, you need to call `Session.run()`.
sess = tf.Session()
x_val = np.random.rand(37, 100, 100)
batch_size_val = sess.run(batch_size, {x: x_val})
print x_val  # ==> "37"
```

See : [get the size of a variable batch dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236175/get-the-size-of-a-variable-batch-dimension)

Answer (score 1):

Could `tf.map_fn` be what you are looking for?

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
f = tf.map_fn(lambda y: y, x) # or perhaps something more useful than identity
```

**EDIT**

Now that I understand better, I think the problem is that you are trying to get the range while the graph is created, as opposed to when the graph is run.

Also, you need to use `tf.range` to query the shape at run time.

```
In [2]: import numpy as np
   ...: import tensorflow as tf
   ...: x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])
   ...: sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
   ...: sess.run(tf.range(tf.shape(x)[0]), {x: np.zeros((7,10))})
Out[2]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: This iterates over the entire domain though. What I need is a list just over the first dimension, and using `tf.shape(X)[0]` in `tf.map_fn` doesn't work. For example if `X` had a shape of `[47, 99]` I just need a list of numbers of `[0, 1, ..., 46]`. But, when building the graph `X` has a shape of `[None, 10]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't operate on tensors that way. You need to use `tf.map_fn` as user1735003 mentioned.

Here is an example where I used `tf.map_fn` in order to pass the output of an LSTM at each timestep into a linear layer, defined by `weights['out']` and `biases['out']`.

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", [features_dimension, None, n_timesteps])

weights = {'out': tf.Variable(tf.zeros([N_HIDDEN_LSTM, labels_dimension]))}
biases = {'out': tf.Variable(tf.zeros([labels_dimension]))}

def LSTM_model(x, weights, biases):
        lstm_cell = rnn.LSTMCell(N_HIDDEN_LSTM)
        # outputs is a Tensor of shape (n_timesteps, n_observations, N_HIDDEN_LSTM)
        outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32, time_major=True)
        # Linear activation
        def pred_fn(current_output):
            return tf.matmul(current_output, weights['out']) + biases['out']
        # Use tf.map_fn to apply pred_fn to each tensor in outputs, along
        # dimension 0 (timestep dimension)
        pred = tf.map_fn(pred_fn, outputs)

        return pred
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a small trick you can use, if you are using tensorflow >= 1.13, although not very efficient, since it uses sorting.

```
x=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None])
xargs=tf.argsort(x)
range=tf.sort(xargs)
```