# How do I read variable length 1D inputs in Tensorflow?

Tags: csv, tensorflow, spectrogram

I'm trying to read variable length 1-D inputs into a Tensorflow CNN.

I have previously implemented reading fixed length inputs by first constructing a CSV file (where the first column is the label and the remaining columns are the input values - flattened spectrogram data all padded/truncated to the same length) using tf.TextLineReader().

This time I have a directory full of files each one containing a line of data I want to use as input (flattened spectrogram data again but I do not want to force them to the same dimensions), and the line lengths are not fixed. I'm getting an error trying to use the previous approach of compiling a CSV first. I looked into the documentation of tf.TextLineReader() and it specifies that all CSV rows must be the same shape, so I am stuck! Any help would be much appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: That would probably help if you showed code and/or data sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the data isn't changing shape when you have a longer or shorter sample right? By that I mean that if you trained your network on arrays of 1000 pixels for example, with a kernel of say `[5,1]` size. That `[5,1]` kernel needs to see the same patterns in the variable length data as it did in the training data. If your data is stretched or shrunk, then the correct solution is to interpolate the data to the same size as the training data so the shapes/patterns match.

Assuming you just want variable length inputs, then in theory you should be able to do this by setting your batch size to 1 and varying the 1st dimension of the data.

So your input placeholder would look like:

```
X = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=[1,None,1,1])
```

The 4 shape arguments are: 1=batch size; None=unknown first dimension size; 1=unused because it's a 1D dataset, 1=one channel images, again unused but necessary for `tf.conv2d` to receive the expected 4D image.

This is not very different from configuring tensorflow to support variable batch sizes. So you should review this link below and understand that process.

[get the size of a variable batch dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236175/get-the-size-of-a-variable-batch-dimension)

Note that you can't use a batch size more than 1 here because you wouldn't be able to construct a matrix with missing values in the 2nd dimension. I expect the convolution operations to work with this variable dimension (though I haven't actually tried this).

Another option to deal with this problem would be to pad your inputs with 0's so they all have a common length, but that will need to have been trained into the model up front.

Comment: Thanks David, I decided to sort my data by the variable length dimension and then do the zero-padding approach within each minibatch. So within each minibatch all the samples have the same length (equal to the max of the minibatch length), but between batches the lengths may vary.

Comment: I have a followup question on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684048/tensorflow-building-graph-with-batch-sizes-varying-in-dimension-1